# Facebook auto share data

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

When user visits my website. i want to do such thing like when they visit my website my website will beautomatically sharedto their facebook profile.  if they are logged into their account.

Comment: You are not allowed to do that – shares should only happen when the user willfully triggers them, but not “automatically” just because you think that was a good way to promote your site.

Comment: If this would happen to me, I would report your site/app/... to facebook since this is very bad dev behavior...